# How to display an image in dashing.io project

Tags: dashing

Please suggest me how to display an image inside dashing application (Im refering application created using dashing.io ruby gem)

Answer (score 5):

Use the Image widget:

```
<li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="1">
  <div data-id="image" data-view="Image" data-title="My Sweet Image" data-image="/logo.png"></div>
</li>
```

Please note, the path `/logo.png` refers to the `/assets/images/logo.png` included in the standard Dashboard. Put your images into `/assets/images`.

Comment: For me it did not work. The browser renders the following html snippet <div data-id="image" data-title="My Sweet Image" data-src="/assets/logo.png" class="widget widget-image image"><img data-bind-src="image | prepend '/assets'" data-bind-width="width" src="/assets" width="undefined">
</div> Somehow the src attribute of the img element does not have the correct value

Comment: But of course, <div data-view="Image" data-image="/logo.png"></div> could simply be used, instead

Comment: You are correct -- https://github.com/Shopify/dashing/blob/master/templates/project/widgets/image/image.html#L1

data-image is the correct attribute, thanks for the fix!

Comment: Thanks for the update! Then, the correct snippet would be simply data-image="/logo.png", without assets prefix